# ImagePullBackOff error backoff github packages azure aks

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, github-package-registry

I am deploying my services Azure AKS. I am running into an issue where I get a `ImagePullBackOff` error. Here is some context.

I have 2 nodepools one with `--enable-node-public-ip` option and another one without the node public-ip enabled option. I am trying to deploy a `Daemonset` resource. The container image is hosted on GitHub package registry. The issue is, the nodes that don't have a public IP enabled are successfully able to pull the images whereas, the nodes that have ppublic-ip enabled has an error.

Here is the error:

```
Failed to pull image "docker.pkg.github.com/xyz": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.pkg.github.com/xyz"
```

I would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 0):

`ImagePullBackOff` and `ErrImagePull` indicate that the image used by a container cannot be loaded from the image registry. Make sure you don't have a typo in image definition.

Try `docker pull docker.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME:TAG_NAME` beforehand. Afterwards, you should give `docker.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME:TAG_NAME` in Daemonset definition.

It is not an authentication issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering this! But I did met the same issue as Gaurav met. I could docker pull; I could start the Deployment and pods on my local minikube; but I cannot create a deployment either on AKS or GKE, any thought or further suggestions? Thanks

Comment: If it is in private registry checkout credentials. It is not an error related with Kubernetes, it is a configuration issue.. If you do the same thing on your machine with k8s, you will get the same result.